# use always get and set methods is a bad practique, is call directly an attribute class a bad practique in OOP?

Tags: object-oriented, clean-code, patterns-and-practices, code-smell, getters

I have a doubt about if there are some recommendations for call directly an attribute in a class

I think that in OOP you always should call an attribute by the get method.

*For example:*

**On set**

```
public setAtribute(Atribute atr){ this.atr = atr;}
```

**On get**

```
 public Atribute getAtribute(){ return this.atr;}
```

**On the constructor**

```
public Constructor(Attribue atr){
    setAttribute(atr);
}
```

If the attribute is injected in the super class I use this way to call it, on inherits class:

```
@Inject
protected Attribute atr;

public Attribute getAttribute(Attribute atr){
    return atr;
}
```

I.E. I prefer to use always get and set in OOP to get access to the attributes.

But in my work there is a debate because there are people that not like this way. Because you can wrote the following code:

```
getAttribute().callSomeFunctionality();
```

But I prefer these instead of:

```
this.callSomeFunctionality();
```

And I think that this not break the Demeter´s Law because is a variable class.

What do you think about that?

Is the best use always the get and set function, or there are other cases to call directly to attribute.

There is some of the literature about this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean only execution WITHIN the object? If so than using 'this' is imho more natural as you don't want to encapsulate object internals from other object internals?

Comment: It depends. There's nothing that "always" is "better" no matter what in software engineering. Are we talking about plain objects (POJOs, POCOS, Mappers, etc)? Are we talking about ANY possible object in any layer?

Comment: @Laiv I am talking in general, for example, and android project with models for get data from the api and ViewModels with MutableLiveData as an attribute, or a game with models for players and objects.

Comment: @kadiii Yes this is more natural, but if the parameter need some of logic in the set or in the get for example? If you put it all logic in the get or in the set you can forgot the problems and get variable in any place

Comment: Then, the answer is "no", "it's not always better". If you consider OOP principles like encapsulation to be anything good.

Comment: Are you familiar with the axioms of the OOP? Encapsulation, high cohesion, loose coupling? Also with the so popular SOLID principles? You will find the answer to the question in these principles and axioms.

Comment: @Tlaloc-ES If you put logic in get or set for class fields then you have bigger problems than one from your question.

Comment: maybe, but in my idea, you need put logic in get and set in some cases for example, in an order list, you put data in and list and you are sort after, and IMHO you do this in the set for that you can forget call the two methods, of course I want read your oppinion about that, An example about that is correctly in some cases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923116/is-it-a-good-practice-to-implement-logic-in-properties

Comment: In which sense is the linked question related to the one here? Having logic within a getter is different than granting everybody with access to the getter.

Comment: In which sense is the linked question related to the one here? Having logic within a getter is different than granting everybody with access to the getter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, the point of OOP is that you *don't need access to the attribute*.
Think about what you want to do with the attribute - whatever that is, should potentially be a method of the class, so you should call that method to do it, instead of getting the attribute value and doing it yourself.

There are exceptions, of course, but if all your 'classes' are only collections of related attributes, and the usage is coded outside of them, it's not OOP.

Comment: I think this too and for these reasons, I like to use get, but is there cases for use call to attribute like in structured programming when you are using OOP approach? is a mix not a bad option?

Comment: Of course, pure OOP is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Of course, pure OOP (in the Alan Kay sense) is a great idea

Comment: I think that it's far easier to read code and refactor classes when a semantically meaningful method is used over accessing properties directly.  For example: if you have a LightSwitch class I want to say `lightSwitch.TurnOn()` instead of saying `lightSwitch.onOffState = true;`